# Differential equation's domain?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm confused a little bit. I have a differential equation:
$yy'\sqrt{(1-x^2)/(1-2y^2)}+1=0$. I just looked at it and solved it without problems, it didn't look like a big deal. It's a nonlinear nonhomogeneous first order differential equation, right? You can separate variables here, so I did it. But when I checked the answer on Wolfram, the answer was different. CAS wxMaxima produced another solution. And then I remembered perhaps I should do something with the domain, or something with the expression I've divided by. I've never really understood those things, because my differential equations course was a chaotic one, no one ever really explained it decently. Oh, so, okay, my question. What I should do about the domain and range of the equation? It looks like $(1-x^2)/(1-2y^2)$ has to be greater than or equal to zero, because it is in the square root. So, numerator and denominator should both be greater than or equal to $0$ OR less than or equal to $0$. Oh, and denominator shouldn't be equal to zero? But how I suppose to solve the dif.equation correctly?
I did this.

1. At first I solve the equation when $x \in [-1,1]$ and $y \in [-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}]$, I got the answer $\arcsin x - \frac{\sqrt{1-2y^2}}{2}=C$.
2. Then I took the case when $x \in [-\infty,-1] \cup [1, +\infty]$ and $y \in [-\infty, -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}] \cup [\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, +\infty]$. The solution I got was  $\frac{\sqrt{2y^2-1}}{2}+\ln{|\sqrt{x^2-1}+x|}=C$

I did it like that, but I don't really think it's a good solution. Perhaps solutions overlap each other and still not sure if it's a correct method to do this. Oh, and Wolfram gave me this answer: $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2y^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\log(-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+1)-\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+1)+C$.

CAS wxMaxima gave me this result: $\frac{2\sqrt{x^2-1}\log(2\sqrt{x^2-1}+2x)\sqrt{\frac{x^2-1}{2y^2-1}}+x^2+1}{2\sqrt{x^2-1}\sqrt{\frac{x^2-1}{2y^2-1}}}=C$

I know that you can simplify the answer of Wolfram and wxMaxima, but why they didn't simplify it? There must be reasons..

So, I don't know why these solutions are differently written, which one of them is the most accurate, how to solve exactly correctly, what should I do about the DE domain (not only this equation's, but also every other time, with different DE) and was my solution good?

And sorry for my ignorance, I'm  really messed up :D I believe there's some small detail I don't understand at all..

Comment: I'm really confused and really interested in this problem.